# When developing a website

Tags: performance

Very often, I just create a new folder and test things out in there. I use remote upload and then edit and refresh the page to see if it works. Now, one time when I was asked to work on a friend's website, he told me to change the IP for his domain in my HOSTS windows file. He had a clone of his website on another server, so I could edit everything and still visually see my work. Is it ideal to work like this? What's a good strategy for programming when developing websites? e.g. Back up before you begin working, working on the files in a separate directory, etc...

I know everyone has their own style and I understand there's no right way. I'm simply just interested in everyone's common practices and I hope to pick up a few tips here and there and incorporate it to my own style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already doing it, start using a version control system like `git` or `subversion` for keeping track of changes.  That way, you'll always be able to revert to an older version if new changes breaks something.

I develop and test changes on my workstation or a development server with a configuration that resembles the web server's config as closely as possible, so that I can be confident that things won't break when I deploy the new version on the web server.  I commit my changes as I go, and when I'm satisfied with the new version I deploy it to the web server by checking out the new version on the server.

Comment: Ha, subversion was mentioned in my other question. Interesting...

Comment: Using version control is excellent advice. No professional developer should be working without. The Pragmatic Programmers advocate this very strongly. Git is rather painless to set up and work with.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddling with the `/etc/hosts` file is a quick and simple way to simulate a Web address for testing purposes - nothing wrong with that at first blush.

However, if decently done then working on the site shouldn't *need* that kind of trickery, because all links inside the site should be relative. i.e. if the original site had an address like `http://true.app.com` and you were testing on a server with address `mock.app.com`, then you should be able to point your browser at `http://mock.app.com` and once you're there all the links should work. If the links are absolute (i.e. the page is full of references to `true.app.com`) then there might be a problem with the design/architecture/structure.

If your friend doesn't have a domain name for his testing server, then the same applies to the numeric address; the links should still work if you start off browsing to `http://1.2.3.4`.

A valid reason for "faking" the address might be if your site does a lot of back-and-forth with another, and the other site's links send your browser back to your site.

To answer the question: A good strategy is to work with relative links as much as possible; that way, when your friend's business and software get sold to another company, or he goes out of business and has to re-surface under another name you'll have much less work adapting the links - ideally, none.

Comment: This is something I should learn and incorporate in to my developing practice.

Comment: I mess around with my hosts a lot, so I use the ShowIP firefox extension to always display what IP I'm pointed to for a particular address.  See it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/590/

Answer (score 1):

Pull the site down (if you're going to edit an existing) to your local development web and database server/workstation. Make it run and develop locally. Have the source (code, images, stylesheets, db scripts and so fourth) go into your own version control system.

Comment: I'm guess you're suggesting something like XAMP or WAMP?

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting this, but there is a chance this solution is painful to set up. There may be a significant bit of work involved in setting up the complete environment of a site; and his working relationship with said friend is obviously not a full-blown employment gig. If the friend can set it up, less work and more power to him!

Comment: Yeah I know, but that's kinda my idea here ^^ Setting it up will give you important knowledge of how the site works AND make you able to actually set it up from scratch if ever needed. I'd always dive into a project making sure it's actually (re)deployable first.

Comment: With regard to the XAMP or WAMP, that's entirely up to you and of course dependant on what platform the site in question uses to begin with.